# Mule: how to turn on SSL handshake logging on HTTP component

Tags: mule

I'm looking for a way to log details of an SSL handshake on a Mule HTTP(S) listener component.

Is it possible to do this via log4j configuration?

I'm using Mule v3.6+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start Mule with this system property: `-M-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`.

Comment: Is there a way to turn the ssl logging for a particular application only?

Comment: No, that is a JVM configuration, applies to all server connections.

Comment: +1 because the message `Use -Djavax.net.debug=handshake for further debugging` didn't work for me, but the `ssl:handshake` part you pointed out did. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use, the following log4j xml to log request on the http component.

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.glassfish.grizzly" level="INFO" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.asynchttpclient" level="INFO" />
    <AsyncLogger name="sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.http.client" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="com.ning.http" level="ALL" />
```

Comment: so which of these will log the SSL handshake?

Comment: sorry about the previous answer, you could use this during run of mule app  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl